# why the websocket client user session is null after connect to server

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I am using this code to connect to websocket with Java 8 in spring boot project:

```
package com. sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client;

import com. sportswin.soa.robot.common.SessionUtil;
import com. sportswin.soa.robot.model.entity.Robot;
import com. sportswin.soa.robot.model.enumn.RobotStatus;
import com. sportswin.soa.robot.service.impl.RobotService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.URI;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
public class WebsocketClientConnector {

    @Value("${com.dabai.robot.ws-url}")
    private String websocketUrl;

    @Autowired
    private SessionUtil sessionUtil;

    public synchronized WebsocketClientEndpoint robotNewConnect(Long roomTypeId, String token, String userMark) {
        WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = null;
        String websocketConnUrl = websocketUrl + "?token=" + token + "&roomTypeId=" + roomTypeId + "&robotFlag=1";
        try {
            String appMark = SessionUtil.getThreadLocal("appMark");
            clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI(websocketConnUrl));
            if (clientEndPoint == null) {
                return null;
            }
            clientEndPoint.userSession.getUserProperties().put("userIdentity", userMark + "-" + appMark + "-" + roomTypeId);
            clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(message -> {
                log.info("addMessageHandler:", message);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Websocket error", e);
        }
        return clientEndPoint;
    }
}
```

when run to get `clientEndPoint.userSession`, the result is null. Why the user session is null when establish connnections? what should I do to make sure the user session exists? When I paste the websocket connection url in webbroswer plugin, it could connect successfully.

[image]

and the eror log output like this:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:488) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client.WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:53) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client.WebsocketClientConnector.robotNewConnect(WebsocketClientConnector.java:35) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client.WebsocketClientUtil.websocketReconnection(WebsocketClientUtil.java:127) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client.WebsocketClientUtil.createWebsocketHandle(WebsocketClientUtil.java:85) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.allowRobotSelfPlay(PlayEntryOperate.java:290) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.addRobotBatch(PlayEntryOperate.java:213) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.handleCommonGame(PlayEntryOperate.java:189) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.lambda$matchByRoomType$4(PlayEntryOperate.java:142) [classes!/:na]
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.matchByRoomType(PlayEntryOperate.java:135) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.allRoomRobotBalance(PlayEntryOperate.java:105) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.playRoomEntry(PlayEntryOperate.java:72) [classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.EnvelopRobotJobHandler.matchTenant(EnvelopRobotJobHandler.java:60) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.EnvelopRobotJobHandler.jobExecutor(EnvelopRobotJobHandler.java:48) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.EnvelopRobotJobHandler.runJob(EnvelopRobotJobHandler.java:40) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:508) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It's isn't null. It doesn't even exist yet. Your code didn't get to that line of code, because it threw an exception at a prior line. It's the exception you should be asking about, not non-existent variables.

Answer (score 1):

You get a timeout exception from here:

```
clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI(websocketConnUrl));
```

You have filled the variable *com.dabai.robot.ws-url* propperly?
I suppose that he variable not filled properly or the host and port in the url is not reachable.

Comment: I am sure set the url properly, because the url always connection successful only the app run a long time with this error.@Maik

Comment: If you had already connection to this URL, check that old programs in your IDE are terminated.
Is your socket maybe closed in another place?
Try to use auto closeables to avoid file descriptor locks (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)